# Partial access control for PHP

Tags: php, permissions, acl

Are there any libraries/solutions that provide a partial access to a resource? How is such such a permission control called?

Most ACL libraries are allowing/denying actions completely:

`user.create 
 user.update 
 user.show`

But what if there should be a "partial" permission. 
Something like:

1. You are only allowed to see *active* users with the role *guest* or *moderator*.
2. You are allowed to edit an user with the role *designer* but only his *phone* and *mail*.

The first example may look like this:

permission:

`user.show`

Privileges:

`status => active
 &&
 role => guest || moderator`

and the second:

permission:

`user.edit`

Privileges:

`editable => phone, mail`

**Update:**

To make my issue more clear, I have added this usage example, to show how (in my ideas) it may look like.

```
// global access
if($user->can('user.show')){
  // get the privileges provided by the permissions
  $filter = $user->getPrivilegesFor('user.show');
  // use the privileges to filter the (database)query
  // (using the example above the filter should restrict to active guests and moderators)
  $result = $repo->getUsers($filter);
}else{
// access denied
}
// use the result to fill the view
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in most of the libraries you have option to extend the class. So you can extend the class user like

```
class myuser extends user{
```

This way you can give whatever role or permission you want for guest or moderators. You can use Codeigniter, Zend and lot of other good frameworks.

Comment: Seems that I haven't took a good example. My problem is not to provide a role to a user, I'm looking for a permission library that allow a more differentiated approach than only allowing or denying an action. In my example there is a permission that allows to show users that are active and belong to the role guest or moderator. There may another permission that allow to see inactive female users, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With Zend Framework 2, you will have `ZfcUser` module which could be coupled with the `bjyauthorize` module. And you'll have that you need with some configuration.

Comment: Haven't used Zend 2 yet, but this module looks more promising than the basic Zend ACL. Have to look if this solves my issue.

Comment: You can define fine grained permissions for users and contents you need to provide. It is very handy to work with.